# Creating new renderings that are compatible with SXA

Tags: best-practices, sxa

I've been playing with SXA and some of the out of the box renderings and rendering variants that come with it. I understand how to create my own rendering variants, and I understand how to create my own renderings in a traditional Sitecore sense. That said, what I can't quite come around to figuring out is how to create new renderings that are peers with those of SXA.

So, what I'm trying to understand is:

- How do I create new, SXA-enabled components that can be used by my content editors from the toolbar?
- What considerations do I need to take in to account to make rendering variants for my new rendering?
- How should I set this up in a solution to stay adherent to Helix principles?

Any guidance on these or reading would be helpful; I haven't found much in the SXA documentation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what I worked out from playing with SxA:

- For your controller renderings, you need to make sure your controller inherits from `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Mvc.Controllers.StandardController`
- Make sure your rendering has a rendering parameters template setup. If you inherit from `/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Rendering Variants/Rendering Parameters/IComponentVariant` and `/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Presentation/Rendering Parameters/IStyling` you will get the variant and styling options added to the properties of the rendering parameters.
- Finally make sure your component is added to the available renderings for your site's presentation:

  [image]

Comment: Did you have to create any items under System or Templates that follow the Helix pattern?

Comment: I created the rendering parameters template under `/sitecore/templates/Feature/mycomponent/Rendering Parameters` - I don't know if it must follow the Helix pattern tho, I just did.

Comment: This is fantastic Richard, thank you. I'm unable to get to my SXA instance today, but I wanted to confirm: are your renderings showing up in the SXA toolbar? Did inheriting from one of the SXA template interfaces enable that? Thanks!

Comment: You need to add your rendering into so called `Available renderings` (you can see it on the screenshot). Those items defines which renderings should be visible in the **Toolbox**

Comment: Yes, of course. Apologies, coffee has not set in yet. Thanks, Richard and Alan.

Comment: I'm seeing an issue that I can't figure out. The goal is to create a new section in the toolbox. I created a new Available Renderings item called Custom, and I've added two new renderings, News and Author.  However, when I go to the toolbox instead of one new section called Custom with two renderings in it, I get two new sections, named News and Author, each with one rendering of the same name in it. Any ideas?

Comment: @AlexTselevich if you have a different issue it would be worth asking it in a separate question. Its more visible that way,