# Create controller rendering in SXA

Tags: mvc, sxa

As a test, I wanted to create a rendering for an SXA site. It had to be added to the toolbox and have a controller, model, and view.

I read this [Creating new renderings that are compatible with SXA](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1921/creating-new-renderings-that-are-compatible-with-sxa) and now I am somehow confused as in that answer only the controller and rendering parameters are mentioned and I remember this slide from the Sitecore Symposium:

[image]

**Here they also mentioned:**

- adding a div to my view
- implementing IRenderingModelBase for the model

**So now my questions are:**

1. Do I need to do add this div to the view and what if I don't?
2. Do I need to implement that interface and what will I benefit (or what will I miss if I don't)?
3. If I have a custom model that implements this interface, what is the best way to fill all the properties involved? I found a `GetModel()` in the controller and a `ModelRepository` that might help but then I need to copy the values..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. You should. Here are few things that you should know.

   Without this `div` element your rendering will not be SXA compliant.

   If you decide to skip it you will lose following features/abilities:

   - your rendering will not be able to use "SXA styles". This `div` is the main wrapper and inside `class` attribute other classes which can be specified in Rendering Parameters will be injected (if your rendering parameters inherit from `/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Presentation/Rendering Parameters/IStyling`).
   - your rendering will not be recognised by **Creative Exchange**. Bear in mind that if you are going to allow designers to export your theme someone can add additional CSS classes and **CE** will not be able to import it then.
   - if you decide to write a rendering with JS logic it is easier to register your JS logic (`XA.register('accordions', XA.component.accordions);`). You don't have to worry about loading order. You just implement 'interface' and your rendering will be initialized when it will be possible.
2. You don't have to. I would say you will never implement this interface directly. What you can do is to use existing `RenderingModelBase` which implements `IRenderingModelBase` and derive from it. This is how it should be done and how it is done in **SXA**. To see whare are the benefits of using that model base class go to **Appendix 1**  to learn more.
3. See how it is filled in `FacebookCommentsRepository`. There is `FillBaseProperties(model);` method which comes from `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Mvc.Repositories.Base.ModelRepository`

```csharp
public override IRenderingModelBase GetModel()
{
    FacebookCommentsRenderingModel model = new FacebookCommentsRenderingModel();
    FillBaseProperties(model);
    model.DataHref = GetDataHref();
    model.PostsCount = GetPostsCount();
    model.ColorScheme = GetColorScheme();
    return model;
}
```

This is how the new simple model could look like. As you can see it derive from `RenderingModelBase` and decorate type with 3 tiny properties.

```csharp
public class FacebookCommentsRenderingModel : RenderingModelBase
{
    public string DataHref { get; set; }
    public string PostsCount { get; set; }
    public string ColorScheme { get; set; }
}
```

#### Appendix 1

`RenderingModelBase` class contains:

```csharp
public Item Item { get; set; }
public Item PageItem { get; set; }
public IRendering Rendering { get; set; }
public Item DataSourceItem { set; get; }
public IEnumerable<string> CssClasses { get; set; }
public MvcHtmlString MessageEditHere { get; set; }
public MvcHtmlString MessageIsEmpty { get; set; }
public string HeadingTag { get; set; }
public bool IsControlEditable { get; set; }
public bool IsEdit { get; set; }
public RenderingWebEditingParams RenderingWebEditingParams { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, List<string>> Attributes { get; set; }
```

I will not describe every property, but some interesting are:

- `IsEditable` - invokes `getControlEditability` pipeline and determine whether your control can be editable. Used to display rendering in a different way in different context
- `MessageEditHere` - this is an auto-formatted string that can be returned to indicate that rendering should be edited **HERE**. Sometimes your rendering may return nothing due to lack of data source or some data. This is s string that should be displayed to make rendering still visible on the page
- `MessageIsEmpty`- this is auto formatted string that can be returned to indicate that rendering has no data source
- `CssClasses` - collection of css classess which I described in **(1)**
- `Rendering` - your current rendering item
- `DataSourceItem` - automatically resolved data source item of your rendering (`Datasource` from rendering parameters)

Answer (score 1):

This is an incomplete answer to start the discussion, but just from what I've found:

The div and the `@Model.CssClasses.Aggregate()` seems to add all of the classes for variants, grid sizing, and other options selected in experience editor to the rendered HTML. I think it would be wise to make sure that's there, from my experimentation, but I have successfully added other renderings I've created before to a page in SXA without this.

For example, when rendered with a carousel with a full bleed image in it, vs the view code:
[image]

The interface, decompiled, shows these properties:

```
public interface IRenderingModelBase
{
  // Properties
  IEnumerable<string> CssClasses { get; set; }
  Item DataSourceItem { get; set; }
  string HeadingTag { get; set; }
  bool IsControlEditable { get; set; }
  bool IsEdit { get; set; }
  Item Item { get; set; }
  MvcHtmlString MessageEditHere { get; set; }
  MvcHtmlString MessageIsEmpty { get; set; }
  Item PageItem { get; set; }
  IRendering Rendering { get; set; }
  RenderingWebEditingParams RenderingWebEditingParams { get; set; }
}
```

Some of those feel obvious, but again, not sure what you're gaining with some of them, either.