# Custom Renderings in SXA

Tags: sxa

For custom renderings that are compatible with SXA, should we always use Controller Renderings?  My understanding is that you **must** use a controller that inherits from SXA's StandardController or VariantsController.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to but it is easier right now as there are only `Controller Renderings` in **SXA**.

We did not create any `View Renderings` so it is not standardised and SXA does not provide any base classes for solutions based on `View Rendering`.

This is probably an area for improvement that **SXA** team could work on.

Of course if you manage to restore all required features on you `View Rendering` you can use them.

The most important part of each component is the following piece of code:

```csharp
<div class="component NAME @Model.CssClasses.Aggregate()">
    <div class="component-content">

    </div>
</div>
```

Consequences of skipping that part can be found here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/2326/16