# Create a custom SXA rendering with variants

Tags: sxa

I managed to create a [custom rendering](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2322/create-controller-rendering-in-sxa) in SXA by inheriting my controller from the `StandardController` (and some other things). But now I would like to create a component that has the ability to work with variants. I saw that there is a `VariantsController`, so I assume that my first step is to use that as base for my custom controller, but what are the other steps I need to take to have 2 variants of my rendering? And what are the options in my view with these variants - what can be altered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should inherit from `VariantsController`. It's very small and all what it's doing is providing `VariantsRepository` (in SXA almost all of logic is placed inside of repositories). It got all what you need to enable your rendering using Rendering Variants.

So the steps you be as follow:

1. Your rendering parameters template should inherit from IComponentVariant
   [image]
2. Your repository should inherit from VariantsRepository
3. Your model which you push to your view should inherit from VariantsRenderingModel
4. Render content using SXA helpers `@Html.RenderingVariants().RenderVariant()`. You can take a look at views of Page Content or Title renderings which are quite simple.