# Custom Rendering Parameters in SXA

Tags: sxa

To add a custom rendering that uses rendering parameters, I saw a blurb on a slide deck that mentioned:

> "Parameters template should implement IStyling (and optionally IComponentVariant)"

`IStyling` sounds like an interface in C#.  This means that I need to create a custom class that implements `IStyling`, right?

For the Sitecore portion, does my template need to inherit anything special inside of the SXA framework?  Also- how do I tie the two together using `RenderingModelBase`?

If anyone could post an example, that would be awesome!

Comment: Actually a combination of the one above and this http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1921/creating-new-renderings-that-are-compatible-with-sxa should answer your question